# Why does my SQS queue not get drained faster when I increase the number of tasks with Fargate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, queue, amazon-sqs, aws-fargate

I have an SQS queue set up, and I had a Fargate Task that is a consumer from this queue. When I manually increased the desired task count from 1 to 10, the SQS queue still kept being consumed at the same pace, and not ten times as fast.

I would expect the SQS queue to be drained faster, since there's more tasks and each task could pick up an event from the queue. I kept seeing the number in flight as 10, not e.g 100, because I increased the number of tasks from 1 to 10. No matter what number I put the desired count of tasks as, (I tried even 100), the in flight number stayed 10, and the SQS queue was not being drained any faster.

Comment: Are you deleting these messages from the queue, once you obtain them in the containers?

Comment: The number of messages in the queue is going down constantly, so I assume they are being deleted as they're processed

Comment: You really need to look at the logs of your tasks to see if they are getting messages or not. It sounds like you may be using an SQS FIFO queue which is blocking other message consumers to ensure exact order message processing.